# Is there an R function to make a copy of all the source code used to generate an analysis?

Tags: r

I have a file run_experiment.rmd which performs an analysis on data using a bunch of .r scripts in another folder.

Every analysis is saved into its own timestamped folder. I save the outputs of the analysis, the inputs used, and if possible I would also like to save the **code used to generate the analysis** (including the contents of both the .rmd file and the .r files).

The reason for this is because if I make changes to the way my analyses are run, then if I re-run the analysis using the new updated file, I will get different results. If possible, I would like to keep legacy versions of the code so that I can always, if need be, re-run the original analysis.

Comment: I don't know that I fully understand, but since you have your `.Rmd` file (with code and processing), and source-data and results in various folders, can you just archive them with `zip` or as a `tar`-ball?

Comment: I want to maintain a history of analyses, but I also want to be able to re-run the analysis using legacy code so that I can make changes to the code while still being able to re-run historical analyses (to see what went wrong, why they behaved the way they did, etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a git repository to commit your code and output each time you update/run it?  I think this is the optimal solution for what you are describing.  Each commit would have a timestamp associated with it for you to rollback to a previous version when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to put all of those scripts into an R package, and in your Rmd file, print `sessionInfo()` to record the package version used.

You should change the version number of the package each time you make a non-trivial change to it (or even better, with every change).
Then when you want to reproduce the analysis, you use the `sessionInfo()` listing to work out which version of R and of the packages to install, and you'll get the same environment.

There are packages to help with this (`pak` and `renv`, maybe others), but I haven't used them, so I can't give details or recommendations.